# Duplicate drop is not working for python even tho it is set

Tags: python

I am trying to drop the following lines:

```
    DATE            EMAILID       SALE  MARKED  LEFT$
    0  10/2/2020      ABC@gmail.com   501     500      1
    1  10/2/2020      123@gmail.com   100     100      0
    2  10/2/2020     test@gmail.com    50      50      0
    3  10/2/2020  example@gmail.com    32      30      2
**4  10/2/2020      ABC@gmail.com   501     500      1**
**5  10/3/2020     test@gmail.com    50      50      0**
    6  10/3/2020      123@gmail.com    75      70      5
    7  10/3/2020  example@gmail.com   100     100      0
    8  10/4/2020  example@gmail.com   200     200      0
```

If 'all' the lines are the same then drop it - but for whatever reason I still get the same out come - can anyone help me.

** means it should be dropped but it isnt

I have tried using:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

But this does not work

Comment: can you show the output after `df = df.drop_duplicates()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the subset and keep parameters for it to work. Check [this one out](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-drop_duplicates).